# Excel: is there a formula/code I can use to paste specific values based on a dropdown value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I’m a new user looking for help on an Excel formula/macro code.

To demonstrate my scenario, let’s say I have a drop down list with values of “Breakfast, Lunch, and Dinner”. If the user selects breakfast from the dropdown, a unique breakfast menu with items and prices as the columns appears below. If the user selects lunch or dinner, a different menu appears below the dropdown cell.

I wish the formula was easy as: IF(A1=“Breakfast”,PASTE(BreakfastMenu) )

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you try the FILTER function? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

Comment: Hi Lee, thank you for the help - the FILTER function works, but the formatting of the menus in my example don’t carry over (for example - the fill color and borders do not appear as they do in the referenced table). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Excel do you have? The more recent versions allow a formula in one cell to spill into an entire range of cells.  That's pretty close to what you want:

```
=IF(A1="Breakfast",Menu!A1:F38)
```

That's pretty rough, though, and it would get unwieldy to input each option. Let's combine that with `IFS()` so we can just stop at the first true result.

```
=IFS(A1="Breakfast",Menu!A1:F38,A1="Lunch",Menu!G1:L38,A1="Dinner",Menu!M1:R38,TRUE,"(Please select a meal)")
```

That will return a lot of `0` values, though, because of all the blanks. Let's roll all that up into one variable and then replace all the blanks with actual blanks instead of 0.

```
=LET(result,IFS(A1="Breakfast",Menu!A1:F38,A1="Lunch",Menu!G1:L38,A1="Dinner",Menu!M1:R38,TRUE,"(Please select a meal)"),IF(result="","",result))
```

Comment: Thank you - the formula worked great. The only problem is that the formatting of the menus does not appear underneath (such as font colors, fill colors, and borders). Is there any way to remedy that within the formula? From my research into this problem, it looks like I may need to use macros to solve it…

Comment: I have version 2302 of Excel. I believe it’s up to date. Thank you again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

To get a copy of values with cells' formatting you can use `Range.Value(11)` property in a UDF. This is an unusual function. It copies its argument from one cell to another, but the function call itself is placed in another non-used cell. Code in a universal module.

```
Function VAL_11(src As Range, dst As Range) As String
      dst.Value(11) = src.Value(11)
End Function
```

Function takes two arguments, the first is source range address, the second – destination address.
Both ranges can be individual cells or rectangular areas with the same dimensions.
This function requires ranges (references) as arguments, so it can be used e.g. with `IFS` function, but not with `FILTER` function. Its return value is an empty string (providing there is no error).
Example of use with the IFS function from the previous post

```
=VAL_11(IFS(A1="Breakfast",Menu!A1:F38,A1="Lunch",Menu!G1:L38,A1="Dinner",Menu!M1:R38,TRUE, Menu!S1:X38), C1:H38)
```

[Sample file is here](https://polslpl-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/mgonet_polsl_pl/EUYqFN6GaM5Milb_V-jwJUIBX_QWq6NntdGiH_dnDqXWPg?e=2xNU0K)